# Trigger doesn't update event

Tags: trigger, update, create-records

with this trigger I can insert new events, but can't update them, if I update an Opportunity or a Task.

```
trigger CreateEvent on Opportunity (after insert, before update) {
List<Event> events = new List<event>();
Set<id> optyIds = new Set<id>();
    //Create new events on Opportunity Creation
    if(trigger.isInsert){
        for(Opportunity opty: trigger.new){
            Event event = new Event();
            event.whatId = opty.id;
            event.ownerId = opty.OwnerId;
            event.Subject = 'Opportunity Due: '+ opty.Name;
           // Integer d = opty.CloseDate.day();
            //Integer m = opty.CloseDate.month();
            //Integer y = opty.CloseDate.year();
            //event.StartDateTime = Datetime.newInstance(y, m, d, 09, 00, 00);
            //event.EndDateTime = Datetime.newInstance(y, m, d, 10, 00, 00);
            event.StartDateTime = opty.CloseDate;
            event.EndDateTime = opty.CloseDate;
            events.add(event);
        }
        if (!events.isEmpty())
            insert events;
    }else if(trigger.isUpdate){
        //Update existing event if opportunity name, closeDate or ownerId is changed
        //Check which if the opportunities satisfy the criteria.
        for(Opportunity opty: trigger.new){
            if(Trigger.oldMap.get(opty.Id).CloseDate != Trigger.NewMap.get(opty.Id).CloseDate || Trigger.oldMap.get(opty.Id).name
              != Trigger.NewMap.get(opty.Id).name || Trigger.oldMap.get(opty.Id).ownerId != Trigger.NewMap.get(opty.id).ownerId)
                optyIds.add(opty.Id);
        }
        events = [SELECT id, startDateTime, endDateTime, subject, ownerId FROM Event WHERE whatId in:optyIds AND subject LIKE 'Opportunity Due:'];
        for(Event event: events){
            event.OwnerId = Trigger.NewMap.get(event.WhatId).ownerId;
            event.Subject = 'Opportunity Due: '+ Trigger.NewMap.get(event.WhatId).name;
            event.StartDateTime = Trigger.NewMap.get(event.WhatId).CloseDate;
            event.EndDateTime = Trigger.NewMap.get(event.WhatId).CloseDate;
            
        
        }
        update events;
    }
        
    }
```

Comment: What error you are receiving?

Comment: No error, if I change the related opportunity or task, the event doesn't be update.

Comment: Your insert trigger should not work. The opportunity Id is not assigned until after insert.

Comment: My insert trigger works, but the created event wasn't related to opportunity. Now I changed my trigger to after insert and the event is related to opportunity (thanks). But if I change the opportunity the event still won't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your issue on the update part of the trigger

```
events = [SELECT id, startDateTime, endDateTime, subject, ownerId FROM Event WHERE whatId in:optyIds AND subject LIKE 'Opportunity Due:'];
        for(Event event: events){
            event.OwnerId = Trigger.NewMap.get(event.Id).ownerId;
            event.Subject = 'Opportunity Due: '+ Trigger.NewMap.get(event.Id).name;
            event.StartDateTime = Trigger.NewMap.get(event.Id).CloseDate;
            event.EndDateTime = Trigger.NewMap.get(event.Id).CloseDate;
            
        }
        update events;
```

The line `event.OwnerId = Trigger.newMap.get(event.Id).ownerId;`

is using `Trigger.newMap` which is keyed by `Opportunity.Id`, not by `Event.Id`

You need to fetch `WhatId` in the query and use that as the lookup key in `Trigger.newMap`

```
events = [SELECT id, WhatId, startDateTime, endDateTime, subject, ownerId FROM Event WHERE whatId in:optyIds AND subject LIKE 'Opportunity Due:'];
        for(Event event: events){
            event.OwnerId = Trigger.NewMap.get(event.WhatId).ownerId;
            event.Subject = 'Opportunity Due: '+ Trigger.NewMap.get(event.WhatId).name;
            event.StartDateTime = Trigger.NewMap.get(event.WhatId).CloseDate;
            event.EndDateTime = Trigger.NewMap.get(event.WhatId).CloseDate;
            
        }
        update events;
```

Comment: Thanks cropredy for your answer.
Now if I create a new opportunity, the trigger creates two events, one of them related to opportunity another one with no relationship.
And if I update this opportunity, the trigger create a new event with no reference to the opportunity. I changed it to before update, but still same problem.

Comment: @AliFazeli - best thing you could do is to edit your original post and include the updated code and the observed behavior. It is too hard for me to know exactly what you have deployed at the moment

Comment: I edited my first post and copy pasted the code.